# Select nested array element with restangular or angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, restangular

I seem to be having difficulty reading/querying a nested json element from an array returned from mongo/ mongoose using either restangular or angular.

I can write to the nested elements but just not read/query.

To clarify the data is returned and held in the $scope.data for example. But how do I write restangular or angular to get the second level key & value from $scope.data.

Updated - Extra Info

This is the data within $scope.data:

```
[
{
    "_id": "551528ecbb8253446cb26e4f",
    "location": "London Office",
    "hostname": "lon-asa-01",
    "device": "Switch-MLS",
    "model": "Cisco 3750",
    "softwareImage": "1.2",
    "serialNumber": "123456",
    "subnets": [
        {
            "range": "10.0.100.0/24",
            "type": "Client"
        },
        {
            "range": "10.0.101.0/24",
            "type": "Server"
        }
    ],
    "ipAddresses": [
        {
            "ipAddress": "10.0.100.1",
            "type": "Inside"
        },
        {
            "ipAddress": "10.0.101.254",
            "type": "Outside"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Using angular I want to be able to {{ data.ipAddresses.ipAddress}} and {{ data.ipAddresses.type}} to get the key/value pair in the nested element so I can

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ data.ipAddresses.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.ipAddresses.ipAddress }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the question is not clear. can you please add an example of what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Updated the main question with extra explanation.

Comment: can you try $scope.ipAddresses = $scope.data.ipAddresses, this will give you an array of objects as: "ipAddresses": [  {"ipAddress": "10.0.100.1",       "type": "Inside" }, { "ipAddress": "10.0.101.254",  "type": "Outside"  }  ] so you should be able to iterate over $scope.ipAdresses using ng-repeat.

Comment: Hi Jax, i've done the following but $scope.ipAddresses doesn't seem to be available either within ng-repeat or {{ ipAddresses.type }}, {{ ipAddresses.ipAddress }}?

Answer (score 2):

what you can do if you want to manipulate by $scope.data

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
    <td>
     {{item.ipAddresses[0].ipAddresses}}
     {{item.ipAddresses[0].type}}

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

where item correpondonds to each element in your array

if you want to manipulate by $scope.data.ipAddresses:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in data[0].ipAddresses">
    <td>
     {{item.ipAddresses}}
     {{item.type}}

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ data[0].ipAddresses[0].type }}</td>
    <td>{{ data[0].ipAddresses[0].ipAddress }}</td>
</tr>
```

Using ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data[0].ipAddresses">
    <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.ipAddress }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This works to a point but if I have multiple top level records setting the [0] places the same .type & .ipAddress for all? How can I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.

In the end this is what worked for me: Yes I know I used ul li but I was just prototyping.

```
<ul ng-repeat="network in networks">
            <li>{{ network._id}}</li>
            <li>{{ network.location}}</li>
            <li>{{ network.hostname}}</li>
            <li>{{ network.device}}</li>
            <li>
                <ul ng-repeat="ip in network.ipAddresses">
                    <li>{{ ip.type }}</li>
                    <li>{{ ip.ipAddress }}</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>{{ network.subnets}}</li>
            <li>{{ network.iosVersion}}</li>
            <li>{{ network.softwareImage}}</li>
            <li>{{ network.serialNumber}}</li>

        </ul>
```